# Save a file every day depending on its name through batch file

Tags: batch-file, task

It is possible to write a batch file that every day it is going to copy a file in a specific folder?

For example, today I have a file named `pinco17-12-2018` and I want it to automatically move in the folder `12`.

Tomorrow I will have `pinco18-12-2018` and it will move in the `12` folder.
Next month, I will have `pinco1-1-2019` and it has to go in the folder called `1`.

How can I do this?

Comment: So all files from january independent of the your should go to the same folder `1`?

Comment: Yep
And the file in february in the 2 Folder

The problem is that the file is created in a folder
And those folder are in another directory also

Comment: Then @Stephan's answer will do. The directories will be created in the current dir (where the batch will only look for `pinco*` files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for %%a in ("%userprofile%\desktop\Files1\pinco*") do (
  for /f "tokens=2 delims=-" %%b in ("%%~na") do (
    md "%userprofile%\desktop\Files2\%%b" 2>nul
    move "%%a" "%userprofile%\desktop\Files2\%%b\"
  )
)
```

Translation into plain English:

- For all files that start with `pinco` in the specified folder do:
- get the month (the second token of the file name when delimited with `-`)
- create a folder with that month in the specified folder (don't show an error, if it already exists)
- move the file into that folder

**about your latest comment (2019-01-07):**

yes, this is possible. Just extend the tokenization of the filename (`%%~nF`), where `%%a` would be the month and `%%b` would be the year:

```
@echo off
for %%F in ("%userprofile%\desktop\Files1\pinco*_*_*) do (
  for /f "tokens=2,3 delims=-" %%a in ("%%~nF") do (
    md "%userprofile%\desktop\Files2\%%b\%%a" 2>nul
    move "%%~fF" "%userprofile%\desktop\Files2\%%b\%%a\%%~nxF"
  )
)
```

Comment: Ok thanks. But where I have to add the Directories? If pinco is created somewhere else than the directory

Comment: Hard to answer without knowing more. Is there a fixed folder where they are created? Or a fixed root, where it is created in or in a subfolder of it? Or just "somewhere on the drive"? Or "somewhere on the system (on any drive)?

Comment: I think is just another Directory on the Desktop.
The file is create on Files1 directory on the Desktop
Always on the Desktop there is another directory called Files2, and in this Directory there are the other folders 1,2,3,4,5,6...(like the months). Another question: i have to Create the script that you writed me in .ps1?

Comment: Edited to implement source and destination paths. You requested [batch-file] (by the tags), so this is a batch file with extension `.bat` or `.cmd`. `.ps1` would be Powershell.

Comment: Is working perfectly, thank you very much.

Last question: it is possible to write an output log to see if the operation is going good or bad?

Comment: add `echo !errorlevel!: %%a>> output.log` after the `move` line. It will give you `0` for success or `1` for fail plus the filename. Or to make it more talking, you can do something like `if errorlevel 1 (echo %%a FAILED>>output.log) else (echo %%a SUCCESS>>output.log)`

Comment: Hi Stephan, I have a new question for you (if you have time).
The script that you created is working perfectly.

Now: if I want that this script create another folder before the "month" one, it is possible?

For Example:

pinco17-12-2018

Now we already create a folder of the month and move the file inside of it.
If I want to create a folder of the year, and then create Inside the folder of the year create the folder of the month?

2018 (folder) --> 12 (folder) ---> pinco17-12-2018 (file)

You think it is possible?

Thank you in advance